# Raised MD and Raised MC unicodes are not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/70tkhpvg/21/) fiddle.I have a textarea and a edit button beside it,when i click on the edit buttton a popover containing symbol buttons appear.

Then when you click on respective symbol,it appears in the textarea.But,unable to insert MD and MC as TM.They are getting inserted differently.

Here is the Code:

**HTML**

```
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="symboltext"></textarea> <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="popbutton" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var popupElement = '<div class="btn-group" role="group"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="regbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="copyrightbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"><span></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="trademarkbtn"><sup>TM</sup></button></div><div class="btn-group" role="group"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="deposee"><sup>MD</sup></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="decommerce"><sup>MC</sup><span></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="degreebtn">&#176;</button></div>';
var lastPoint=0;
$('#popbutton').popover({
    animation: true,
    content: popupElement,
    html: true
});

function textbox()
{
    var ctl = document.getElementById('symboltext');
    var startPos = ctl.selectionStart;
    var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd;
    lastPoint = startPos;
    return {s:startPos,e:endPos};
}

function getVal(insert){
   var val=$("#symboltext").val();
    var index = textbox();
    val = val.slice(0,index.s) + insert + val.slice(index.s)
    lastPoint+=2;
    return val;
}

$(document).on('click', "#trademarkbtn", function () {
   var val=getVal("\u2122 ");
    var input=$("#symboltext");
    input.val(val).focus();
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = lastPoint;
});


$(document).on('click', "#regbtn", function () {
     var val=getVal("\u00AE ");
   var input=$("#symboltext");
    input.val(val).focus();
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = lastPoint;
});

$(document).on('click', "#copyrightbtn", function () {
      var val=getVal("\u00A9 ");
    var input=$("#symboltext");
    input.val(val).focus();
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = lastPoint; 
});
$(document).on('click', "#deposee", function () {
      var val=getVal("\u1F16B");
    var input=$("#symboltext");
    input.val(val).focus();
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = lastPoint; 
});
$(document).on('click', "#decommerce", function () {
      var val=getVal("\u1F16A");
    var input=$("#symboltext");
        input.val(val).focus();
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = lastPoint; 
});
$(document).on('click', "#degreebtn", function () {
      var val=getVal("\u00B0");
    var input=$("#symboltext");
    input.val(val).focus();
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = lastPoint; 
});
```